# Solving NullPointerException Error in Android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am new to Android and Java as well. I am coming from PHP.
The following code is taken from a Book (Pro Android 4 App Dev - Reto Meier):
Here is an Android Code where I am facing problem:

File: EarthquakeListFragment.java

```
public class EarthquakeListFragment extends ListFragment {

    ArrayAdapter<Quake> aa;
    ArrayList<Quake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<Quake>();

    private static final String TAG = "EARTHQUAKE";
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        int layoutID = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<Quake>(getActivity(), layoutID, earthquakes);
        setListAdapter(aa);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                refreshEarthquakes();
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }

    public void refreshEarthquakes() {

        // Get the XML
        URL url;
        try {
            String quakeFeed = getString(R.string.quake_feed);
            url = new URL(quakeFeed);

            URLConnection connection;
            connection = url.openConnection();

            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                // Parse the earthquake feed
                Document dom = db.parse(in);
                Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

                // clear the old earthquake
                earthquakes.clear();

                // Get a list of each earthquake entry.
                NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("entry");
                if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        Element entry = (Element) nl.item(i);
                        Element title = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName(
                                "title").item(0);
                        Element g = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName(
                                "georss:point").item(0);
                        Element when = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName(
                                "updated").item(0);
                        Element link = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName(
                                "link").item(0);

                        String details = title.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        String hostname = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov";
                        String linkString = hostname
                                + link.getAttribute("href");

                        String point = g.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        String dt = when.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
                        Date qdate = new GregorianCalendar(0, 0, 0).getTime();

                        try {
                            qdate = sdf.parse(dt);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Date parsing exception.", e);
                        }

                        String[] location = point.split(" ");
                        Location l = new Location("dummyGPS");
                        l.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(location[0]));
                        l.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(location[1]));

                        String magnitudeString = details.split(" ")[1];
                        int end = magnitudeString.length() - 1;
                        double magnitude = Double.parseDouble(magnitudeString
                                .substring(0, end));

                        details = details.split(",")[1].trim();

                        final Quake quake = new Quake(qdate, details, l,
                                magnitude, linkString);

                        // Process a newly found earthquake
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                addNewQuake(quake);
                            }
                        });

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (HttpHostConnectException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "HttpConnection Error.");
        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Parser Config Exception");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SAX Exception");
        } finally {

        }
    }

    private void addNewQuake(Quake _quake) {
        // add the new quake to our list of earthquake
        earthquakes.add(_quake);

        // Notify the array adapter of a change
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

Here is part of the LogCat, where error is showing:

> 09-09 20:03:15.689: W/dalvikvm(1095): threadid=11: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930) 09-09 20:03:15.735:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1095): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-111 09-09
>   20:03:15.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-09 20:03:15.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):   at
>   com.satyaweblog.earthquake.EarthquakeListFragment.refreshEarthquakes(EarthquakeListFragment.java:106)
>   09-09 20:03:15.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):   at
>   com.satyaweblog.earthquake.EarthquakeListFragment$1.run(EarthquakeListFragment.java:50)
>   09-09 20:03:15.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 09-09 20:03:20.015:
>   I/Process(1095): Sending signal. PID: 1095 SIG: 9

So, at one place, the line of code is:

```
String point = g.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

In PHP, I would have checked this way:
var_dump(g);
How to check here in Android + Java?

I think, 2nd error will be due to first!

Comment: if you are using Eclipse, if you double clicked this line :

com.satyaweblog.earthquake.EarthquakeListFragment.refreshEarthquakes(EarthquakeListFragment.java:106) 09-09 20:03:15.735:

in your LogCat, it will send you to the line where it threw the Exception, Runtime Exceptions are always shown in the line after the "cased by : NullPointerException" line, if you found your class name in this next line, double click it to go for the error

also make sure to initialize your methods local variables since the compiler some times dont know when it is called, and so it may cause a compiler error for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the problematic line

```
String point = g.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

it is possible that `g` is `null`.

```
 Element g = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName(
                            "georss:point").item(0);
```

as [`NodeList#item(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html#item%28int%29)

> Returns the indexth item in the collection. If index is greater than
>   or equal to the number of nodes in the list, this returns null.

It is also possible that [`Node#getFirstChild()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getFirstChild%28%29) returns `null`. Its javadoc states

> The first child of this node. If there is no such node, this returns
>   null.

Take a look at the XML you retrieve. Chances are there is no child node.

Comment: Here is the xml file link: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/1day-M2.5.xml
I see 1st Entry is not having <georss:point/>. It is telling that the feed is deprecated. Possibly that is the reason for code not working?

Comment: @SatyaPrakash Don't use `getElementsByTagName` when using namespaces. Use `getElementsByTagNameNS`. The first won't find anything with value `"georss:point"`. Also consider using XPath.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but getElementsByTagName is working now after two times Eclipse start and surly xml file name change (http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.atom?format=xml).

Comment: @SatyaPrakash Good to hear. Glad I could help.

Comment: Now, I see date Exception is coming but app is running.
09-09 20:48:37.815: D/EARTHQUAKE(1396): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-09-09T07:50:31.641Z" (at offset 19).
Is this not correct? 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");

Comment: @SatyaPrakash You should ask a new question, but basically that is telling you that the format you need (your `SimpleDateFormat` object) cannot be used to parse the date you get. You need two `yy`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37064/discussion-between-satya-prakash-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Answer (score 0):

Change `for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)` code to `for (int i = 1; i < nl.getLength(); i++)`

it will work as the xml code on the link has been expired. So for 0th index it is getting the deprecated message.

for start the for loop from `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`